# $10$ apples, gives $3$ away. How many ways can she do this?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Jill has ten apples, and plans to give at most three of them to Jack. How many ways can she
do this?

Would this simply just be $C(10,3)$?

Comment: Are the apples distinguishable?

Comment: I don't think so. Because if they were then wouldn't the answer be $P(10,3)$

Comment: Both answers are wrong for both cases...

Comment: Actually it wouldn't be $P(10,3)$ unless order counts.  Also, beware you said “at most”.

Comment: Note the condition "at most three" apples to be given to Jack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the number of ways Jill can give **at most** three apples to Jack.

So we need to count the one way Jill can give **no** apples to Jack, add to that the number of ways she can give **one** apple to Jack, and then add to that the number of ways she can give **two** apples to Jack, and then add to all of that the number of ways she can give **three** apples to Jack:

$$1 + C(10,1) + C(10, 2) + C(10, 3)$$

Comment: Wow... Definitely should have read that more closely. Thank you for clarifying it!

Comment: You're welcome!